# Get just one row per ID from SQL query with specifc condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm using Postgres v>9.

I'd like to get values of a table like this:

```
id  year   value
1   2015   0.1
2   2015   0.2
6   2030   0.3
6   2015   0.4
6   2017   0.3
```

The idea is to get lines where years is < 2019 or year = 2030. If id is repeated, I´d like to get only 2030 line, not 2015 ones, that is, the result I´m looking for is:

```
id  year   value
1   2015   0.1
2   2015   0.2
6   2030   0.3
```

How can I do that?

Comment: what is an id has more than one but no 2030?

Comment: I´m simplifying the question.

Comment: About [PostgreSQL versioning](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/).

Answer (score 1):

This only considers the year 2030 or any year < 2019. At least that's what the question says. (I suspect there's something fuzzy there.)

It picks one row per `id`, with the latest year first.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) *
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY id, year DESC
WHERE (year = 2030 OR year < 2019);
```

If there can be multiple rows with the same `(id, year)`, you need a tiebreaker.
About this and more details for `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: This won't get more than one value for id = 6?  or the year desc handles that?

Comment: Exactly one row per exisiting `id`. Ample explanation in the provided link.

Answer (score 0):

Use `distinct on` if you want one row per id:

```
select distint on (id) t.*
from t
order by id, year desc;
```

Comment: Ok, but I need a specific row, only the "year 2030" one for id = 6.

Comment: @MauroAssis . . . That is the row that is returned, given the data you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT ID,
        FIRST_VALUE(YEAR) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY YEAR DESC RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS year,
        FIRST_VALUE(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY YEAR DESC RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS value  
 FROM t 
 WHERE YEAR = 2030 OR YEAR < 2019
```

I think this is the standard for first_value -- postgre might require a seperate clause?

Comment: I'd to add a DISTINCT keyword after SELECT in your suggestion, and it worked.

Comment: oh that is right, I always forget the distinct when using first values with no groupby.

Comment: Tks, Hogan, I already put in the "real" sentence and it worked like a charm!